# FFMPEG from Inside Blender

Tags: rendering

Can I use FFMPEG straight from blender instead of using the available formats and codecs? Can someone show me an alternative for that?

Comment: I don't think so, but using ffmpeg independently is not that difficult. Are you trying to render straight to video, are you using an image sequence, or combining video in the VSE?

Comment: Todd I want to reduce my workflow steps, render straight to codec mp4v decoded to Planar 4:2:o YUV and my needs are, codec mp4 avc (part10) (avc1) using the same decoder.

Comment: Are you rendering out raw animated/composited image data or mixing video in the VSE? If it's the former, I would strongly recommend rendering to an image sequence and then using ffmpeg to convert the sequence to the video file you need. You might be able to trigger the external ffmpeg call from python in Blender following the render event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render to Adobe Captivate from Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33744/render-to-adobe-captivate-from-blender)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution to launch ffmpeg automatically following Blender's completion of rendering out an image sequence:

```
import bpy
import os

bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)

ffmpegPath = "YOUR-PATH-TO-FFMPEG-APP"

imgPath = "YOUR-PATH-TO-IMAGE-OUTPUT-FOLDER"

#frame filename format assuming "0001.png"
imgNamePattern = "%04d.png"
vidOut = "test.avi"
vCodec = "mpeg4"

ffmCMD = ffmpegPath 
ffmCMD += " -start_number 1 -i " 
ffmCMD += imgPath + imgNamePattern 
ffmCMD += " -vcodec " + vCodec + " " 
ffmCMD += imgPath + vidOut

print("launching ffmpeg")
os.system(ffmCMD)
```

Comment: Ok, let me know how it works. Getting the file paths right will be critical. What OS are you on?

Comment: Im using unfortunately windows 7 64.

Comment: Should still work, just find the path to the ffmpeg.exe file. On OSX, you have to look within the app file to find the actual executable, which is the reason I asked. Have you been able to get it working?

Comment: I´m going to finish a few motion graphics stil to try it later, but from what I´ve seen on the code everything should work, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`.